# Excluding assemblies from code coverage in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: code-coverage, azure-devops

I have a build running on Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online). I want to exclude some of the assemblies from code coverage calculations. Based on a format I've read [from](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj159530.aspx) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508534/how-to-exclude-projects-with-names-ending-in-test-from-my-code-coverage-analy) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458246/using-runsettings-to-exclude-assemblies-from-code-coverage). I have created a .runsettings file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" 
          uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0"
          assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>*AWSSDK*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

But this produces the following error:

Starting test execution, please wait...
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous operation on process stream.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardError()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Vanguard.Wait()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Vanguard.Start(String outputName, DataCollectionContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollectorImpl.StartVanguard(DataCollectionContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.UnitTestDataCollector.SessionStart(Object sender, SessionStartEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector.SessionStart(Object sender, SessionStartEventArgs e)
at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
at WEX.TestExecution.TaefDataCollectionEvents.OnSessionStart(SessionStartEventArgs e)
at WEX.TestExecution.DataCollectorTestMode.Initialize(ITestModeSettings settings, ICallbackRegistrar callbackRegistrar)
Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1

Yes, some of the tests are using async/await. The same .runsettings file works fine in Visual Studio 2015. If I do as it suggests and add the following option: `/UseVsixExtensions:true`, the result is the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: And with the runsettings file you provided, no testing should be found. The format should like "<ModulePath>.*AWSSDK.*</ModulePath>".

Comment: Can you set "system.debug" variable to "true" when queue the build and then share the entire logs?

Comment: Surprisingly, changing the content of `ModulePath` per your recommendation solved the problem. Strikes me that the `InvalidOperationException` is misleading, maybe even some bad exception handling? [Here's the logs](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=47707C5E85187AB1!450&authkey=!AHgwV59SruF7j3Q&ithint=file%2czip) with system.debug=true for a build where ModulePath is `*AWSSDK*` (and fails).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runsettings file use following regex expressions to match the files:

> Regular expressions Include and exclude nodes use regular expressions.
>   For more information, see Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio.
>   Regular expressions are not the same as wildcards. In particular:
>
> .* matches a string of any characters
>
> . matches a dot ".")
>
> ( ) matches parentheses "( )"
>
> \ matches a file path delimiter "\"
>
> ^ matches the start of the string
>
> $ matches the end of the string

With your original path, all the files will be excluded since you have only "*" in the path. Refer to this link for details: [Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

For the bad exception, According to the logs your provided, you are running the build with Hosted Build Agent. I did a quick test with Hosted Build Agent and can reproduce this issue too. However this issue does not occur when I try with my own build agent. I suspect that there is some setting/configuration on Hosted Build Agent cause this issue and I have help your submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page. You can check this link for tracking: [Invalid exception when run testing from Hosted Build Agent](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2638150)

Comment: Nice one Eddie. Perfect explanation, and going beyond the call by immediately creating a bug report.