# Cannot exclude assemblies when using coverlet 3.2.0 and a .runsettings file

Tags: nunit, .net-6.0, coverlet

I am trying to run unit tests using NUnit and coverlet but exclude assemblies that end with the name `.Testing` from the coverage report. However, whatever I do the file (for example `MyProj.Testing.dll`) is being added in the coverage report (other assemblies I don't want in the report, such as test assemblies, are not present).

I am using the following coverlet packages in my test assemblies:

- `coverlet.msbuild 3.2.0`
- `coverlet.collector 3.2.0`

I am using a `.runsettings` file to configure coverlet.

`coverlet.runsettings` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>./CodeCoverage/</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <Format>cobertura</Format>
          <ExcludeByAttribute>Obsolete,GeneratedCodeAttribute,CompilerGeneratedAttribute,TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode</ExcludeByAttribute>
          <IncludeTestAssembly>false</IncludeTestAssembly>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*Testing\.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

I have looked at:

- [How to exclude Projects with names ending in ".Test" from my code coverage analysis in VS2012 Unit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508534/how-to-exclude-projects-with-names-ending-in-test-from-my-code-coverage-analy?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Using .runsettings to exclude assemblies from code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458246/using-runsettings-to-exclude-assemblies-from-code-coverage)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017

I have also tried:

- Removing the Include section
- Setting the Exclude/ModulePath to: `.*Testing.*`
- Using Sources/Exclude/Source instead of ModulePath

I have been trying to do this seemingly trivial thing for hours but am now out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes, runtimesettings files are quite nasty. Try to run your command with debug log to see, what is happening.
dotnet test --settings runsettings --diag:log.txt .

Otherwise, you can explicitly mark the project assembly itself to exclude from code coverage & coverlet will exclude them in the coverage file.

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Project>

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue, and after some research I discovered that coverlet uses another format to exclude assemblies. The documentation is here https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md

So the filter in runsettings would be something like:

```
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <Format>opencover</Format>
                    <Exclude>[*Testing*]*</Exclude> <!-- [Assembly-Filter]Type-Filter -->
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```