# How to exclude or include a group of tests under NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I'm a new NUnit user, using NUnit 3.9 under Visual Studio Community 2017. I'm using it on a pet open source library project, and it's going well once I got the hang of it.

The library accesses a publicly available government website via a documented API. Most of my tests use local data, so that I have a stable bed to compare against, and so that I can test without going out to the website every time.

I would like to set it up so that normally, the tests that hit the server do not run. I run the tests over and over as I tweak the code, and just as a matter of courtesy, don't want to bang on the server. Also, I'd like to be able to test even when the remote system is down or when I don't have Internet access.

Is there any way to group or tag my tests so that normally only the ones using local data run, but that I can still, when necessary, run the ones that exercise the server access? Either specifying "run these" or "exclude these" would be fine.

I've grouped the tests into two different classes, UnitTestOffline.cs and UnitTestOnline.cs, and was hoping I could somehow run the tests on a class-by-class basis, but haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get better answers if you say specifically how you run your tests, since there are a number of ways to do it. Since you mention VS2017, I'm going to assume that you are using the NUnit 3 VS Adapter, but let us know if you are using some other approach.

In the VS adapter, use the dropdown to display your tests by class. Right click on the class for which you want to run tests and run them.

If you decide to categorize tests using the `CategoryAttribute`, you can display tests by "trait" in Visual Studio. As before, right click on the group you want to run tests for and run them.

If you get a lot of tests, you might want to put your unit tests in one assembly and your integration tests in another. In that case, display the tests by project, right click on the project you want and run them.

All of this can also be done using the nunit3-console command-line runner as well. To select by class or category, you use the `--where` option. To select by assembly, you merely enter the name of the assembly you want on the command-line.

Comment: Thank you, Charlie. It's probably my newness to NUnit that made me not realize there are a number of ways to run the tests. I use the menu item Test / Run to run them. I see some options like "Selected Tests", "All Test", "Failed Tests", but not what you're referring to. I'm not particularly attached to this method, though.

The VS adapter docs at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter say what it is, but not how to launch it. Is it from within VS?

Sounds like the categorization is just what I need.

Comment: After adding a category to the UnitTestOnline.cs [TextFixture], now in the Test Explorer, I see a dropdown that lets me organize by "Traits." Perfect.

In fact, I see it would also let me select by Class, so I could have used that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to [categorize your tests](http://nunit.org/docs/2.4.8/category.html) (unit test, integration tests...) and run only the unit tests... you could use `[Category]` for that.

In the nunit GUI you could /include /exclude category after that and run only the one you want.

And probably that the filtering of Visual Studio could work.

Try to see one of the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582025/how-to-exclude-certain-tests-in-the-visual-studio-2012-test-runner) as well